# How does GPermission work?

Tags: permissions, glib, gobject

`GPermission` seems to have little to no documentation. How do you actually use it? (I'm currently using it for a GTK LockButton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the documentation is pretty lacking.  GPermission is an abstract base class which isn't particularly useful by itself.  You need something which actually implements GPermission, like [polkit](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/PolkitPermission.html).

There are some examples in gnome-control-center, like the [datetime panel](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-control-center/tree/panels/datetime/cc-datetime-panel.c).

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass `GPermission`.  When you need to change the values, you call `g_permission_impl_update`.  Very non-intuitive, but yeah that's how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Google found me this straight away: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.26/GPermission.html

Is that not sufficient?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not clear to me. I've read that page many times, but there's no usage examples, specifically for setting permissions. Both properties are read-only.